# GTM collect user ip address

Tags: google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

I have embeded the GTM script to

```
    <!– Google Tag Manager –>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({‘gtm.start’:
new Date().getTime(),event:’gtm.js’});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=’dataLayer’?’&l=’+l:”;j.async=true;j.src=
‘https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=’+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,’script’,’dataLayer’,’GTM-XXXX’);</script>
<!– End Google Tag Manager –>
Additionally, paste this code immediately after the opening <body> tag:
<!– Google Tag Manager (noscript) –>
<noscript><iframe src=”https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX”
height=”0″ width=”0″ style=”display:none;visibility:hidden”></iframe></noscript>
<!– End Google Tag Manager (noscript) –>
```

I am doing GDPR and I have concerns about the way to collect data from GTM. The GTM auto collect user IP address, is that right?

Comment: Probably your question is related not to Tag Manager but to a third-party service like Google Analytics.

Comment: @splunk  yes, we control Google Analytics by GTM, and we have created some custom events to trigger the on/off cookies of 3rd party. Now, we are concerned if we embed the GTM script to the page, but only triggering on/off cookies when the user accepts the cookies. So, is it valid with GDPR?